# Editing side-bar

Tags: feature-request

On Stack Overflow if I click 'edit' under a post I am taken to the editing page for that post. The page has a sidebar stating:

How to Edit

- fix grammatical or spelling errors
- clarify meaning without changing it
- correct minor mistakes
- add related resources or links
- *always* respect the original author

Our site does not include this side bar. Is there a reason that we omit editing guidance at the point of editing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are still in beta. I think this refers only to graduated sites.

That said, we are currently undergoing graduation so as soon as the graphic design is complete we will be a full graduated site. And I'm assuming that we will then have that edit info.